# django+flex: Debugging strategies

Tags: python, django, actionscript-3

I love django, and I like flex. Django for it's cool debugging system (those yellow pages helps a lot to find bugs in my code), and flex for it possibilities.

Recently I come across a problem. If I create a form in flex and then communicate with the django server, I can't see any debugging info (when the exception happens in django).

Not sure, if there is a way to get the debugging info, because it is not accessible in command line (no error output), or in firebug....

Also I tried to create a quick html form, and post same data as I send from flex form, but it's a bit of pain to be honest.

Will be happy to listen how do you solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used firebug to debug the flex side of things. But I've been using json or XML for communication between the two. Since flash uses the browser to do the network stuff, the request should be visible in the net tab of firebug.

To debug the django side of things, you have a few options.

1. If you're using the django dev server, you can add print statements to find out what's going on.
2. You can write a unit test to see if the django side of things is doing what you expect it to, given known data.
3. You can use the pyDev debugger to run the django dev server and step through your code.

I use a combination of these to debug my code.